# How to output multiple rows from an existing table in a stored procedure using oracle sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an existing Customers table and want to output each row from this table using a stored procedure. There is no input criteria, just need to output all of the records.

The stored procedure should basically be equivalent to:
 "SELECT C_ID, LAST, FIRST, DOB, DPHONE, EMAIL FROM customers;"

This seems simple but I can't figure it out. All my searches haven't worked out for this case.

How would one accomplish this?

EDIT: Answered my question below. Very simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
In Oracle your options are:
1. Use a function and return a REF CURSOR
2. Use a procedure and use a REF CURSOR as an OUT parameter
3. Use a PIPELINED function
4. Use a function and return a collection.
```

read this documentation
[Overview of Table Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDIIFEG)

see similar question here [Return collection from packaged function for use in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888990/return-collection-from-packaged-function-for-use-in-select)

simple sample of such function

```
CREATE FUNCTION StockPivot(p refcur_pkg.refcur_t) RETURN TickerTypeSet
PIPELINED IS
  out_rec TickerType := TickerType(NULL,NULL,NULL);
  in_rec p%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH p INTO in_rec; 
    EXIT WHEN p%NOTFOUND;
    -- first row
    out_rec.ticker := in_rec.Ticker;
    out_rec.PriceType := 'O';
    out_rec.price := in_rec.OpenPrice;
    PIPE ROW(out_rec);
    -- second row
    out_rec.PriceType := 'C';   
    out_rec.Price := in_rec.ClosePrice;
    PIPE ROW(out_rec);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE p;
  RETURN;
END;
/
```

Comment: Sorry @are, I just answered my own question. It was basically as easy as I imagined. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Just got it. It is pretty simple. I just did this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CustomerReport AS
BEGIN
   FOR cus IN (SELECT C_ID, LAST, FIRST, DOB, DPHONE, EMAIL FROM customers)
      LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(cus.C_ID||' '||cus.FIRST||' '||cus.LAST||' '||cus.DOB||' '||cus.DPHONE||' '||cus.EMAIL);
      END LOOP;                          
END;
```

Comment: do you need just print this records? not return them?

Comment: yep lol. Very simple, I'm just new to loops in sql so I couldn't get it.