# PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00913

i am trying to create a sql function that prints the reservations made by a customer when his name is beeing given. The customers names are in a table called CLIENTS.FNAME CLIENTS.MNAME CLIENTS.LNAME and the reservations searched by  an id- foreign key 
there is the code for the function that shows a 'too many values" error, maybe it has to be done by Loop or something?

```
create or replace FUNCTION cl_reserv(clName VARCHAR2)

RETURN RESERVATIONS%ROWTYPE

IS
resRecord RESERVATIONS%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT RESID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,ADDINFO INTO resRecord
           FROM RESERVATIONS INNER JOIN CLIENTS ON RESERVATIONS.CLIENTID=CLIENTS.CLIENTID
           WHERE clName IN (FNAME,MNAME,LNAME);
RETURN resRecord;
END;
```

Comment: the select returns more than one record, you try to insert the list of records into one variable - and server raises the exception

Comment: see this article "how to return collection form pl/sql function" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888990/return-collection-from-packaged-function-for-use-in-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SELECT clause doesn't match with the record you're trying to select into. Change your code like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cl_reserv(clName VARCHAR2)
    RETURN RESERVATIONS%ROWTYPE 
IS
    resRecord RESERVATIONS%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT r.* INTO resRecord
           FROM RESERVATIONS r INNER JOIN CLIENTS c ON r.CLIENTID=c.CLIENTID
           WHERE clName IN (FNAME,MNAME,LNAME);
    RETURN resRecord;
END cl_reserv;
```

By using `r.*`, you select exactly the number, type and sequence of columns that are needed for the record type.

Comment: or alternatively, you could specify the record fields to be returned into, e.g. `SELECT RESID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,ADDINFO INTO resRecord.resid, resRecord.startdate, resRecord.enddate, resRecord.addinfo from ...`

Comment: thank you, for the help. When i am calling the function i am still getting error regarding the result. i am trying to get the lines with information from resRecord. 
'code' DECLARE
res RESERVATIONS%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  cName := cl_reserv('Ivan');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
END; 'code'