# Oracle 12c table function to select subset of rows with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, table-functions, select-for-update

I have a requirement to return a subset of rows from a table using `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. Based on application parameters this subset may or may not be ordered by a column. I can't use `ROWNUM` since the numbers are assigned before `SKIP LOCKED` happens, so using cursors and `FETCH ... LIMIT` seems to be the way to go.

That works using an anonymous PL/SQL block, but I need to expose the data back to the java application. The most straightforward way would be to use a table function, so I can just do `SELECT * FROM table(my_function(<params>))`.

I tried a standard table function returning a collection first, but I got the error `[902] ORA-00902: invalid datatype`. This is roughly what I had in place:

Package specification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ACTIVITY_UTILS AS

TYPE ActivityList IS TABLE OF ACTIVITY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;

FUNCTION activity_batch(batch_size IN INTEGER, order_by_source IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN ActivityList;

END ACTIVITY_UTILS;
```

Package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ACTIVITY_UTILS AS
FUNCTION activity_batch(batch_size IN INTEGER, order_by_source IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN ActivityList
IS
    batch ActivityList := ActivityList();
    selectStatement VARCHAR2(200);
    TYPE CursorType IS REF CURSOR;
    activitiesCursor CursorType;
BEGIN
    IF UPPER(order_by_source) = 'TRUE' THEN
        selectStatement := 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVITY_TABLE ORDER BY source FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED';
    ELSE
        selectStatement := 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVITY_TABLE FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED';
    OPEN activitiesCursor FOR selectStatement;
    FETCH activitiesCursor BULK COLLECT INTO batch LIMIT batch_size;
    CLOSE activitiesCursor;
    RETURN batch;
END activity_batch;
```

While debugging the ORA-00902 error I ran into this question:
[Return collection from packaged function for use in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888990/return-collection-from-packaged-function-for-use-in-select)

My (limited) understanding was I was trying to use a PL/SQL type on plain SQL, which is not allowed. I tried using a pipelined table function, as mentioned in the answer, but then I got the error `ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query`.

This seemed odd, is `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` considered DML? At any rate, I noticed I could [workaround this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729236/solution-to-cannot-perform-a-dml-operation-inside-a-query) by using `pragma autonomous_transaction`, but that defeats the purpose of having `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`.

My question is, is this requirement achievable at all using functions, or would I have to use a procedure with an `OUT` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: create a function (or procedure) that returns a cursor and let your java application fetch it normally.

Option 2: Use [Implicit statement results](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1): in this case your java application can run something like `call proc()` where proc returns implicit statement results.

PS. It's not a good idea to hide DML under SQL select...